# Optimizing parallelism in reactive mode with adaptive scaling

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a job which has about 10 operators, 3 of which are heavy weight. I understand that the current implementation of autoscaling gives more or less no configurability besides max parallelism. That is practically useless as the operators I have will inevitably choke if one of the 3 ends up with insufficient slots. I have explored the following:

1. Set very high max parallelism for the most heavy weight operator with the hope that flink can use this signal to allocate subtasks. But this doesn't work
2. I used slot sharing to group 2 of the 3 operators and created a slot sharing group for just the other one with the hope that it will free up more slots. Both of these are stateful operators with RocksDB being the state backend. However despite setting the same slot sharing group name, they're scheduled independently and each of the three (successive) operators end up with the exact same parallelism no matter how many task managers are running. I say slot sharing doesn't work because if it did, there would have been more available slots. It is curious that flink ends up allocating an identical number of slots to each.
3. When slot sharing is enabled, my other jobs are able to work with very few slots. In this job, I see the opposite. For instance, if I spin up 20 task managers each with 16 slots, then there are 320 available slots. However once the job starts, the job itself says ~275 slots are used and the number of available slots in the GUI is 0. I have verified that 275 is the correct number by examining the number of subtasks of each operator. How can that be? Where are the remaining slots?
4. While the data is partitioned by a hash function that ought to more or less distribute data randomly across operators, I can see that some operators are overloaded while others aren't. Does flink try to avoid uniformly distributing load for any reason, possibly to reduce network? Is there a way to disable such a feature?

I'm running flink version 1.13.5 but I didn't see any related change in recent versions of flink.

Comment: For what it's worth, the sort of fine-grained tuning you are attempting is often counter-productive. Usually the best approach is to set the overall parallelism to something high enough to meet the needs of the busiest operator, leave slot sharing enabled (as it is by default), and let the rest follow automatically. To provide more specific advice for your use case, we need more details. For a start, it would help if you could share an image of the job graph.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! Do subtasks running in the same slot share memory as well? If I have rocksdb based stateful operators running alongside sources, sinks and simpler functions, then won't memory become an issue? CPU utilisation would improve but I wasn't sure if memory requirement would increase